# SQLite Update syntax

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

Whats wrong with this SQLite statement?

```
update HOME_TEMP ab 
set ab.REALIMEI=(select substr(cd.IMEI ,1,14) from HOME_TEMP cd where ab.MSISDN=cd.MSISDN)
```

> SQL Error [1]: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near
> "ab": syntax error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `AS` to alias the table being updated (And it's not recognized (Or needed) in the column name to set):

```sql
update HOME_TEMP AS ab 
set REALIMEI=(select substr(cd.IMEI, 1, 14)
                 from HOME_TEMP cd
                 where ab.MSISDN=cd.MSISDN)
```

See the definition of a `qualified-table-name` in the [`UPDATE` documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's not syntactically correct to alias the table that you want to update.
This is the correct syntax:

```
update HOME_TEMP  
set REALIMEI=(
  select substr(cd.IMEI, 1, 14) 
  from HOME_TEMP cd 
  where HOME_TEMP.MSISDN = cd.MSISDN
)
```

Comment: thanks, Works in oracle, I thought it would work here.